# kube-lego not working because of a specific error

Tags: kubernetes, x509, kube-lego

We have kube-lego setup so the certs should've auto-renewed.  It didnt and according to the logs below it seems to be a problem with reaching the sites:

```
time="2019-08-28T22:17:26Z" level=warning msg="authorization failed after 5m0s: reachability test failed: Get https://my.website.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/_selftest: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid" context=acme domain=my.website..com
time="2019-08-28T22:17:26Z" level=error msg="Error while processing certificate requests: no domain could be authorized successfully" context=kubelego
time="2019-08-28T22:17:26Z" level=error msg="worker: error processing item, requeuing after rate limit: no domain could be authorized successfully" context=kubelego
```

I have looked into all the solutions I could google.  I have killed the coredns pods and killed the kube-lego pod but it has not resolved the issue

Comment: What version of Kubernetes do you use ? Keep in mind that the latest Kubernetes release that kube-lego officially supports is 1.8 which is quite obsolete now. The officially endorsed successor is cert-manager.

Comment: When this was deployed I think we had an older version of kubernetes running in AKS.  I dont "think" it was 1.8 old but def older then the version we had to update to recently for a critical patch (as per Azure's email notification).  Thats probably a big reason why its not working.  I'll get to work on migrating it over to cert manager.  I saw that info before but it never occured to me to check version

Comment: I had some struggles with Cert-Manager (the instructions aren't 100% correct)

Comment: which instructions aren't clear for Cert manager? Changing to Cert Manager is definitely the way, we setup on an AKS instance using this https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html, the only thing we had to do was disable the webhooks functionality